# Finding the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in $\frac{(x-3)}{(x^2-3x+2)}$

Tags: combinatorics, generating-functions

First, the given answer is: $$-2 + (\frac{1}{2})^{51}$$

I have tried solving the problem as such:

$$[x^{50}]\frac{(x-3)}{(x^2-3x+2)} = [x^{50}]\frac{2}{x-1} + [x^{50}]\frac{-1}{x-2}$$ 
$$ = 2[x^{50}](x-1)^{-1} - [x^{50}](x-2)^{-1}$$ 
$$=2\binom{-1}{50}-\binom{-1}{50} = \binom{-1}{50} = \binom{50}{50} = 1$$

which is different from the correct answer. Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong here?

**Edit:**
As Did mentions in the comments, $$2[x^{50}](x-1)^{-1} = -2\binom{-1}{50} = -2 \neq 2\binom{-1}{50}$$

Also, $$- [x^{50}](x-2)^{-1} = [x^{50}]\frac{1}{2-x} = \frac{1}{2}[x^{50}]\frac{1}{1-\frac{x}{2}}$$
$$ = \frac{1}{2}[x^{50}](1-\frac{x}{2})^{-1} = \frac{1}{2}\binom{-1}{50}(\frac{-1}{2})^{50}$$
$$=(\frac{1}{2})^{51}$$

Both added together gives the correct answer, which is the correct solution using the original method.

Comment: There is no need to multiply by $x^{50}$, you are going fine up until the second line. Use the formulas for summation $sum_{k=0}^{\infty}x^k=\frac{1}{1-x}$ to find the value of the coefficients.

Comment: @ReverseFlow Sorry if I'm not being clear, but the $[x^{50}]$'s on the second line aren't multiplication by $x^{50}$, I'm just taking out the constants and calculating the coefficient of $x^{50}$ in the remaining terms, such as $(x-1)^{-1}$

Comment: There might be two mistakes here: first, $$[x^{50}]\frac{2}{x-1}= -2[x^{50}](1-x)^{-1} =-2\binom{-1}{50}\ne+2\binom{-1}{50}.$$ Second, $$[x^{50}](x-2)^{-1}\ne\binom{-1}{50}.$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The beginning looks good, but I do not see how you justify the last line. I would use the geometric series instead:

$$\begin{align*}\frac{x-3}{x^2-3x+2} &= \frac{2}{x-1} - \frac{1}{x-2}\\
&= -2\frac{1}{1-x} + \frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{1-\frac 12 x} \\
& = -2 \sum_{n=0}^\infty x^n + \frac{1}{2}\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{x^n}{2^n}
\end{align*}$$

From that we can easily see that $$[x^{50}]\frac{x-3}{x^2-3x+2} = -2+\frac{1}{2^{51}}$$